# Combination of arrays of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I need to combine all the possible arrays of object in javascript.
There are different levels of arrays with values, and it has to be mixed in all the possible ways.

I think I should go for a recursive call but not familiar with it.
Please help me to figure this out.

For the clear question, here is input and output example.

Input:

```js
[
  [{
    level: 1,
    value: "a"
  }, {
    level: 1,
    value: "b"
  }],
  [{
    level: 2,
    value: "c"
  }, {
    level: 2,
    value: "d"
  }],
  [{
    level: 3,
    value: "e"
  }, {
    level: 3,
    value: "f"
  }]
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  [{
    level: 1,
    value: "a"
  }, {
    level: 2,
    value: "c"
  }, {
    level: 3,
    value: "e"
  }],
  [{
    level: 1,
    value: "a"
  }, {
    level: 2,
    value: "c"
  }, {
    level: 3,
    value: "f"
  }],
  [{
    level: 1,
    value: "a"
  }, {
    level: 2,
    value: "d"
  }, {
    level: 3,
    value: "e"
  }],
  [{
    level: 1,
    value: "a"
  }, {
    level: 2,
    value: "d"
  }, {
    level: 3,
    value: "f"
  }]
  [{
    level: 1,
    value: "b"
  }, {
    level: 2,
    value: "c"
  }, {
    level: 3,
    value: "e"
  }],
  [{
    level: 1,
    value: "b"
  }, {
    level: 2,
    value: "c"
  }, {
    level: 3,
    value: "f"
  }],
  [{
    level: 1,
    value: "b"
  }, {
    level: 2,
    value: "d"
  }, {
    level: 3,
    value: "e"
  }],
  [{
    level: 1,
    value: "b"
  }, {
    level: 2,
    value: "d"
  }, {
    level: 3,
    value: "f"
  }]
]
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code you've written in an effort to solve this yourself. Please remember that SO is here to help you debug code, not to write it for you

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still working on it and trying to save time. I apologize if I come off as so selfish.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about simply iterating over all levels you have and know? Then you can store triplets and are guaranteed to have each possibility

```
options = []

for (const level1 of levels[0]) {
    for (const level2 of levels[1] {
        for (const level3 of levels[2] {
            options.push([level1, level2, level3])
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: This can be a good idea, but I'm also considering of the case more than certain number of levels like dynamic as well. I appreciate your answer though.